# Pygame won't draw or fill screen

Tags: python

I posted this question yesterday, but I accidentally posted the wrong code. The program still doesn't work though. I am trying to make a game using pygame and my pictures come from an app called Pixel Art Studio. When I run the code though, I don't get any error messages, just a blank, white screen. I'm following a python programming book called Hello World but this is an original program. Please tell me what I've done wrong, here's my code.

```
import pygame, sys 
guyimages = ['swordsmanguy.pxm','swordsmanstabup.pxm','swordsmanstabstraight.pxm','swordsmanstabdown.pxm']
legsimages = ['swordsman.legs1.pxm','swordsman.legs2.pxm','swordsman.legs3.pxm','swordsman.legs2.3.pxm','swordsman.legs2.2.pxm']
class avatar(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprit.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(guyimages["swordsmanguy.pxm"])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [250, 250]
        self.angle = 0

def animate():
    screen.fill([255,255,255])
    screen.blit(avatar.image, avatar.rect)
    pygame.display.flip

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([960, 640])

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    animate()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set self.image you reference the `guyimages` list like it's a dictionary. Additionally, there seem to be some parentheses missing from your code. Do you get an error in the terminal / command prompt window from which you run this script?

Comment: Thank you I actually missed this error message:                                                                                                      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\swordsmantester.py", line 25, in <module>
    animate()
  File "C:\Python27\swordsmantester.py", line 14, in animate
    screen.blit(avatar.image, avatar.rect)
AttributeError: type object 'avatar' has no attribute 'image'
>>>I'm not sure how to make the code look like code so please tell me that, but also how do I fix this? @maksel

Comment: I believe you need to change `avatar.image` and `avatar.rect` to `self.image` and `self.rect`. `image` and `rect` aren't static variables belonging to your avatar class.

Comment: I'm really sorry to bother you like this @maksel , but that still doesn't fix anything. I just get this error message:                                                                                         Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\swordsmantester.py", line 26, in <module>
    animate()
  File "C:\Python27\swordsmantester.py", line 15, in animate
    screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined

Comment: I just noticed you need to indent the entire `animate` function. Right now, it's not a method of the `avatar` class, making self undefined.

Comment: I did what you said @maksel and now I just get an error message saying that the animate() function isn't defined, and It still won't draw or fill screen. BTW, thank you so much for helping me out on this.

Comment: If you want to call `animate`, you need to instantiate an object since the method `animate` isn't static. So above your `while` loop, add something like `myAvatar = avatar()`. This creates an object of type `avatar`. Then change `animate()` in your loop to `myAvatar.animate()`. Also, change `def animate()` in your class to `def animate(self)` since it's part of a class now.

Comment: I've done that and now when I run it, it says __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (one given). Also, I forgot about this but the pygame window stays normal for 2 or 3 seconds and then says (not responding) and when I try to close it it says "windows searching for a problem" and then I close it. Please help @maksel

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parentheses after animate in the code you posted.

```
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    animate #HERE MISSING PARENTHESES
```